# PHP: How to display value to textbox that has an apostrophe?

Tags: php

I'm having a problem displaying the value of textbox that has an apostrophe.
In my code below, the result will only show `sample` without an s. How can I make the `s` show?

```js
<?php
$str = "sample's";

echo "<input type='text' value='".$str."' />";
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `htmlspecialchars()` with `ENT_QUOTES`

```
echo "<input type='text' value='".htmlspecialchars($str,ENT_QUOTES)."' />";
```

Comment: its working fine for me. have you added anything extra??

Comment: i got it now. I use your code together with the code given by @chandresh_cool which is the stripslashes($str).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) function

```
$str = addslashes("sample's");
```

While echoing use

```
echo stripslashes($str);
```

Comment: While echoing, you can use stripslashes.

Comment: I tried it just now and the result is "sample". still without an s

Answer (score 0):

You could try either:

```
echo '<input type="text" name="name" value="'.$str.'" />';
```

or

```
echo "<input type='text' name='name' value=\"{$str}\" />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$str = "sample's";

echo "<input type='text' value='".str_replace("'", '&#39;', $str)."' />";
```

Note I have useed ISO Latin-1 code for HTML special character here.
You can find special characters related codes here https://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html